# In this representation of the tree of life, what are the lateral connections?

Tags: evolution

[image: Text]

I found this simple representation of the tree of life in a wikipedia article, and I was curious what these horizontal connections shown here are supposed to be, like the ones between plants and protists, or bacteria and protists going to plants. Do they represent things like lateral gene transfer or potential endosymbiotic origin relationships? (like the theory that eucaryotes came from a merging of a bacteria with an archae).

Comment: they likely represent the inclusion of mitochondria and chloroplasts into eukaryotic cells.

Comment: thanks john, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, pretty much! Lateral branches here indicate endosymbiotic events and major horizontal gene transfers.

I'd warn though that the diagram is not very accurate, and additions I'd make would complicate it further as a bush (rather than a tree). Each branch root itself is an instance of cladogenesis, and for this reason the diagram is not very accurate (e.g. [fungi and metazoans seem to arise within the same "branch"](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1116759)), and also misses a few lateral branches that otherwise exist. My favorite example of atypical horizontal gene transfer is that of [prokaryote-insect transfers which occur frequently](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35853453/). This has been known for some time; [many insects contain genes of *Wolbachia* origin](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32131363/) and some (not all) are definitively functional, and are understood to facilitate obligate (fully-dependent) mutualisms.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Very interesting stuff. You mind if I bother you for a recommendation for a book reference on this topic? I've been reading "Assembling the tree of life" which I'm really enjoying, but I was curious if there was a newer reference (the book is from the early 2000s), that is as large in scope as this one, since from what I've heard phylogenetics has grown quite a lot with computational models in the last 20 years.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I am familiar with the most recent literature on the most comprehensive phylogeny of all life available. Perhaps you could take a look at the Tree of Life Explorer [OneZoom](https://www.onezoom.org), maintained for years and most recently [a publication with plenty of explanations was made about it in 2021](https://doi.org/10.1111/2041-210X.13766). You're right, we still catalogue new species and next-gen sequencing and related tools are helping resolve a lot of phylogenenies quickly. To compile all this is a mammoth task, and is of course ever-ongoing.